# error msg in VBA when calling a COM server created in Python using Win32

Tags: python, vba, winapi, com

I'm reading Mark Hammond's book on Python and win32 using the pieces of code below (creation of a mini COM server mimicking Python's `<variable.split>` function, as well of a tiny client on VBA sending a string to be split.

My problem is that although everything seems to be peachy (the COM server is registered and does exist on regedit), I get the French version of the VBA error:

> Code 438 : "property or method not managed by this object".

Needless to say that I did create a specific reg_clsid using `pythoncom.CreateGuid()` !

Environment : Windows 10, Python 3.5.2 under Anaconda 4.1.1, ASUS 8GB 64bits

Many thanks in advance.

Python part :

---

```
 class PythonUtilities:
     _public_methods_ = ['SplitString']
     _reg_progid_ = "PythonDemos.Utilities"

     _reg_clsid_ = "{C44B2DFA-3E19-478C-9599-3DFE7A0D619A}"

 def SplitString(self, val, item=None):
     import string
     if item != None: item = str(item)
     return string.split(str(val), item)

 if __name__=='__main__':

     print("Registering COM server…")
     import win32com.server.register
     win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(PythonUtilities)
```

Messages on the console :

---

```
Registering COM server…
Requesting elevation and retrying...
Registering COM server…
Registered: PythonDemos.Utilities
```

VBA part :

---

```
 Sub TestPython()

     Set PythonUtils = CreateObject("PythonDemos.Utilities")
     myResp = PythonUtils.SplitString("Hello from VB")
     For Each Item In myResp
         MsgBox (Item)
     Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: The VBA error seems to indicate a problem with the registered typedef.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently, others had the same problems in 2012 already : see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805498/how-can-i-debug-run-time-error-438-for-object-written-with-win32com-and-python]. No solution was apparently found.

Comment: Something I forgot to mention : the error msg appears at the level of the VBA instruction 'myResp = PythonUtils.SplitString("Hello from VB")', *not* at the CreateObject line as seems to have been the case in the linked post above. Sorry for that.

Comment: I see that when you register the component this way it creates both InProcServer32 and LocalServer32 keys under the CLSID with the InProcServer32 being `pythoncomloader27.dll` and the LocalServer32 being running `C:\Python27\pythonw.exe "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\server\localserver.py" {C44B2DFA-3E19-478C-9599-3DFE7A0D619A}`. Why won't you remove the InProcServer32, and change the LocalServer32 to `C:\Python27\python.exe -m pdb "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\server\localserver.py" {C44B2DFA-3E19-478C-9599-3DFE7A0D619A}` and try to debug it? (After reading it...)

Comment: + Write a small C++ client to pinpoint the failed action. Each VB line is a gazillion actions. (Where does the `QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch)` happen? In the CreateProcess line or at the method call line?)

Answer (score 0):

In your code `SplitString` is not a member of `PythonUtilities` (regard indentation). Therefore, the function you want to call is not part of the object you have created.
Also, you do not need the `import string` within your function.
Try the following:

```
import pythoncom
import win32com.client

class PythonUtilities:

    _public_methods_ = ['SplitString']
    _reg_progid_ = "PythonDemos.Utilities"
    _reg_clsid_ = "{C44B2DFA-3E19-478C-9599-3DFE7A0D619A}"

    def SplitString(self, val, item=None):
        if item != None: item = str(item)
        return str(val).split(item)

def run_testclient():
    obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("PythonDemos.Utilities")
    print(obj.SplitString("Hello from VB"))

if __name__=='__main__':

    print ("Registering COM server...")
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(PythonUtilities)

    run_testclient()
```

A little bit late. But maybe it still can help...

Comment: would you know how I could return a #N/A type of VT_ERROR (for Excel) ?
I have tried `VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_ERROR, 2042)` but this returns an Error 448 seen from Excel (a DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND = -2147352572)